# Pascal error: left side cannot be assigned when trying to compile

Tags: pascal

I got this error when trying to compile.
[image: pascal error image]

left side cannot be assign to, ./number 21,22 in pastebin

here is my code

```
Program urut;
Uses Wincrt;
Const N =  5;
   data:  Array [1..N] Of Integer =  (2,4,5,3,1);
Var
   j,k,temp :  Integer;
Begin
 Clrscr;
Writeln ('Data sebelum diurutkan');
For j:=1 To N Do
   Begin
     Writeln('data[' ,j, ']= ',data [j]);
  End;
For j:=1 To N-1 Do
  Begin
     For k :=N Downto j+1 Do
        Begin
           If data[k] < data[k-1] Then
              Begin
                 temp := data[k];
                 data[k] := data[k-1]; //left side cannot be assigned to
                 data[k-1] := temp; //left side cannot be assigned to
              End;
        End;
  End;
Writeln;
Writeln ('Data setelah diurutkan ');
For j:=1 To N Do
   Begin
      Writeln ('data[' ,j, '] = ',data[j]);
   End;
 Writeln;
 End.
```

> sorry for uncorrectly pattern post
>   , thank you so much.

Comment: Array `data[]` is declared as a `const`. Therefore it can't be changed.

Comment: Thank you so much, my promblem is solved. How to close this question?

Comment: You can "close" the question by "accepting" the answer [**see here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). You can accept your own answer to your own question, but it will not take effect until 48 hours later, and you will not be rewarded reputations. I suggest you visit the [**help center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read especially about asking and answering. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Like tom Tom Brunberg says, my array is const, it can't be changed. Therefore I need to remove that const.

So it should be

```
data: Array [1..5] Of Integer = (value);
```

without const, and put it under var with another variable